# Can't boot from Fedora PreUpgrade image

Tags: fedora, grub, upgrade

I have been happily using, for several months, Fedora 12 on a PC with a crashed Windows XP3 as the other operating system, and have just used `preupgrade` to download Fedora 16, which now appears as the second entry in my `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file.

Booting with this as the default entry just hangs up the machine. So, my question is: what do I do now to complete the upgrade?

I have searched the Internet and found a lot of relevant entries, but they are all either long out-of-date, or just too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The preupgrade thing in Fedora works *only* for around 2 disttribution steps, and it definitely wasn't available for Fedora 12. Your best bet is to install from scratch, your system is probably very messed up right now.